# Update the Label control one by one using C# code

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a label control in windows form and i have a code as shown below:-

I have added some extra lines here in the code what i have done further. But, still the Label control is not updating one by one.

```
 void function1()
 {
     FOLDER1 = DRIVE + @":\Foldername1";
     LOGFILE1 = FOLDER1 + @"\Foldername2";


     Process msbuild;
     msbuild = new Process();

     DEVENV = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VS100COMNTOOLS") + @"..\IDE\devenv.exe";

     var list = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(LOGFILE1);
     foreach (var item in list)
     {
         System.IO.File.Delete(item);
     }


     // Creation of array of string to Build Projects before Building Up.      
     array[0] = @"\make\versionupdate\versionupdate_vs2010.sln   /build  Release";

    for (int k = 0; k < array.Length; k++)
    {
         msbuild.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
         msbuild.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

         msbuild.StartInfo.Arguments = FOLDER1 + array[k] + @" /out " + LOGFILE1;

         msbuild.StartInfo.FileName = DEVENV;
         msbuild.Start();

         msbuild.WaitForExit();
         UpdateProgress();
    }
}

void UpdateProgress()
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        MethodInvoker method = new MethodInvoker(UpdateProgress);
        Invoke(method);
        return;
    }

    if(checkbox1.Checked)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < array.Length; k++)
        {
            this.lbl_CurrentProject.Text = "Current Project: " + @"  " + array[k];
            progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(((k * 100) / array.Length).ToString());
            progressBar1.CreateGraphics().DrawString(((k * 100) / array.Length).ToString() + "%", new Font("Arial", (float)10.25, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new PointF(progressBar1.Width / 2 - 10, progressBar1.Height / 2 - 7));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            progressBar1.PerformStep();
            progressBar1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
     private void bn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkbox1.Checked)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb_drive.Text))
            {
                DRIVE = "-";

            }
            else
            {
                DRIVE = cmb_drive.GetItemText(cmb_drive.SelectedItem);
            }

            if (thread1 != null)
            {
                thread1.Abort();
            }


            thread1 = new Thread(function1);
            thread1.Start();

          }
        }
```

What is happening here is the label control is not updating one by one. I want to update the label control as and when the projects is building in an array of strings and not all at once.

Please, help me with the above code.
Thanks.

Comment: You are doing the work on the UI thread. You need to use a background worker to achieve the progress.

Comment: is function1 running in a separate thread?

Comment: ok can you help me with some sort of code  @George87

Comment: yes function1 is running in separate thread @GarrGodfrey

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `BackgroundWorker` because You can not update Controls from another thread.

**The right way -** is using BackgroundWorker for your purposes. Another way (almost right way) - use `Control.Invoke` method. And one more another almost right way - use SynchronizationContext.

E.g  Delegate to update progressbar      **As per your last comment you can  use delegatemethod like below**

```
void UpdateProgress()
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        MethodInvoker method = new MethodInvoker(UpdateProgress);
        Invoke(method);
        return;
    }


        if(checkbox1.Checked)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < array.Length; k++)
            {




this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                this.lbl_CurrentProject.Text = "Current Project: " + @"  " + array[k];

                progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(((k * 100) / array.Length).ToString());
                progressBar1.CreateGraphics().DrawString(((k * 100) / array.Length).ToString() + "%", new Font("Arial", (float)10.25, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new PointF(progressBar1.Width / 2 - 10, progressBar1.Height / 2 - 7));
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                progressBar1.PerformStep();
                progressBar1.Refresh();
});
            }

}
```

Comment: I have tried this but the label still not updating one by one ?????  @Anant Dabhi

Answer (score 0):

As usual (and already mentioned by others) you can't do any long-running work within the gui thread or it will freeze and the user can't interact anymore. For this purpose the [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) exists. It runs the payload in another thread and allows easy returnment to the gui thread to update the gui either while it is running (through [`ReportProgress()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx)) or when it is finished (through [`RunWorkerCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) callback).

I just wrote down a simple example, which shows the concept of using the background worker (and maybe the one or other technique to improve your code):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // ToDo: Refactor this into a method that will be called
    //       on some kind of event (eg. button click).
    var rootFolder = @"D:\Root";
    var outputFolder = Path.Combine(rootFolder, @"\Bin\Release");

    var solutions = GetAvailableSolutions(rootFolder);
    var arguments = solutions.Select(solution => String.Join(" ", solution, "/build Release", "/out " + outputFolder));
    var processes = arguments.Select(CreateMsBuildProcess);

    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += OnWorkerDoWork;
    worker.ProgressChanged += OnWorkerProgressChanged;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += OnWorkerRunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

    // ToDo: Disable start button
    ClearFolder(outputFolder);
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(processes);
}

private IEnumerable<String> GetAvailableSolutions(String rootFolder)
{
    // ToDo: Change retrieving of .sln files to any logic you alike.
    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootFolder, "*.sln", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}

private void OnWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var index = 0;
    var worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    // ToDo: Give in a self created class instead of process to easier
    //       access the needed text for ReportProgress().
    var processes = (IEnumerable<Process>)e.Argument;

    foreach (var process in processes)
    {
        if (worker.CancellationPending)
            break;

        worker.ReportProgress(index, process.StartInfo.Arguments);
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}

private void OnWorkerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var text = (String)e.UserState;

    // ToDo: Update label and progress bar.
    // Eg. label.Text = text; progressBar.PerformStep(); or progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void OnWorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // ToDo: Enable Start button.
    // Eg. buttonStart.Enabled = true;
}

private static void ClearFolder(String folder)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(folder))
        Directory.Delete(folder, true);

    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
}

private static Process CreateMsBuildProcess(String arguments)
{
    var devEnvPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VS100COMNTOOLS"), @"..\IDE\devenv.exe");

    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        Arguments = arguments,
        FileName = devEnvPath
    };
    var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };

    return process;
}
```

### Update due to comment: What am I doing wrong?

More or less everything. Seems that you didn't spend any time with the code example I provided, cause I showed how to use a `BackgroundWorker` and you used a `Thread` (the wrong way). Seems that you luckily picked a good day of mine. So I'll give you the code you need to provide in your form (or control) constructor and what you have to call in your button click event:

```
private BackgroundWorker _Worker;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Maybe other stuff you initialize within the ctor...

    _Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _Worker.DoWork += OnWorkerDoWork;
    _Worker.ProgressChanged += OnWorkerProgressChanged;
    _Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += OnWorkerRunWorkerCompleted;
    _Worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    _Worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
}

private void bn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string drive;

    if (checkbox1.Checked)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb_drive.Text))
        {
            drive = "-";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            drive = cmb_drive.GetItemText(cmb_drive.SelectedItem);
        }

        if (_Worker.IsBusy)
        {
            _Worker.CancelAsync();
            // ToDo: Update gui by disable buttons, etc and show that cancelation is pending.
            //       The enabling of the buttons, etc should happen in OnWorkerRunWorkerCompleted()
            return;
        }

        var rootFolder = Path.Combine(drive + ":", "Foldername1");
        var outputFolder = Path.Combine(rootFolder, @"Foldername2");

        var solutions = GetAvailableSolutions(rootFolder);
        var arguments = solutions.Select(solution => String.Join(" ", solution, "/build Release", "/out " + outputFolder));
        var processes = arguments.Select(CreateMsBuildProcess);

        // ToDo: Disable start button and update gui that processing has started.
        // btn_Start.Enabled = false;

        ClearFolder(outputFolder);
        _Worker.RunWorkerAsync(processes);


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with the above code which i have edited, where i am doing wrong ??  @Oliver

Comment: Sir I have solved my problem without  using backgroundworker Class. Well, thanks for the help. I got lot of ideas from your code. Thanks.   @Oliver